# Where does Apache Storm store tuples before a node is available to process it?

Tags: apache-storm, distributed-computing

I am reading up on Apache Storm to evaluate if it is suited for our real time processing needs.

One thing that I couldn't figure out until now is — Where does it store the tuples during the time when next node is not available for processing it. For e.g. Let's say spout A is producing at the speed of 1000 tuples per second, but the next level of bolts(that process spout A output) can only collectively consume at a rate of 500 tuples per second. What happens to the other tuples ? Does it have a disk-based buffer(or something else) to account for this ?

Comment: You should also consider [Heron](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/flying-faster-with-twitter-heron) which seems to be next generation of Storm.

Comment: Thanks! Is Heron open source ? Couldn't find a git link through google search. Is that blog the only source of information ?

Comment: It's on [GitHub](https://github.com/twitter/heron) and has a proper [webpage](https://twitter.github.io/heron/).

Comment: Thanks !! definitely useful.

Comment: What about Apache Flink (flink.apache.org) ? There are other alternatives, too. Btw: Storm made huge progress and I am not sure if Heron is still superior to it (it might have been, a couple of year back though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storm used internal in-memory message queues. Thus, if a bolt cannot keep up processing, the messages are buffered there.

Before Storm 1.0.0 those queues may grow out-of-bound (ie, you get an out-of-memory exception and your worker dies). To protect from data loss, you need to make sure that the spout can re-read the data (see https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html)

You could use "max.spout.pending" parameter, to limit the tuples in-flight to tackle this problem though.

As of Storm 1.0.0, backpressure is supported  (see https://storm.apache.org/2016/04/12/storm100-released.html). This allows bolt to notify its upstream producers to "slow down" if a queues grows too large (and speed up again in a queues get empty). In your spout-bolt-example, the spout would slow down to emit messaged in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Typically, Storm spouts read off of some persistent store and track that completion of tuples to determine when it's safe to remove or ack a message in that store. Vanilla Storm itself does not persist tuples. Tuples are replayed from the source in the event of a failure.

I have to agree with others that you should check out Heron. Stream processing frameworks have advanced significantly since the inception of Storm.

Comment: What about Apache Flink (flink.apache.org) ? There are other alternatives, too. Btw: Storm made huge progress and I am not sure if Heron is still superior to it (it might have been, a couple of year back though)